# Getting com.ibm.wsspi.sib.core.exception.SIConnectionDroppedException in WAS 8.5

Tags: jms, websphere-8

Our application uses WAS SIB for JMS implementation and while posting to a queue on WAS 8.5, getting following exception
javax.jms.JMSException: CWSIA0067E: An exception was received during the call to the method JmsMsgProducerImpl.: com.ibm.wsspi.sib.core.exception.SIConnectionDroppedException: CWSIJ0047E: An operation was attempted on a connection that is already closed..
        at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsMsgProducerImpl.(JmsMsgProducerImpl.java:456)
        at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsQueueSenderImpl.(JmsQueueSenderImpl.java:60)
        at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsQueueSessionImpl.instantiateProducer(JmsQueueSessionImpl.java:224)

Answer (score 0):

We face the same issue. 
Assumption: You are holding a connection longer than you should. In our case I suspect the persistent messaging as cause. If the underlying DB connection is dropped and you hold the JMS connection longer then this error appears.